# Handler that returns inserted record

Tags: spring, kotlin, reactor

If I'm using reactive repository in spring (using kotlin) and I want to return the inserted record.  How do I do it?  I need an operator that will subscribe to what flatMap returns then pass it to a function so that I can use `ok().body(fromObject(insertedRecord))`

Things I tried:

1. `then`: does not return the value
2. `.subscribe { Mono.just(ServerResponse.ok().build()) }` : returns `Disposable`

```
@Component
class RecordHandler(private val repository: RecordRepository) {
    fun create(req: ServerRequest): Mono<ServerResponse> {
        return req.bodyToMono(RecordDTO::class.java)
                .flatMap { repository.insert(it.toDomain()) }
                .then(ok().build())
}
```

The other alternative is to query after the insert but that's a workaround.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
 return req.bodyToMono(RecordDTO::class.java)
            .flatMap { repository.insert(it.toDomain()) }
            .flatMap { ok().body(fromObject(it)) }
```

?

Comment: it is saying it is expecting 

`Mono<ServerResponse>` but I'm giving it `Mono<Mono<ServerResponse>>`

Comment: that did it, thanks.  I can't believe it's that simple.  Is it the fromObject the one subscribing to the result of the Mono coming from insert?

Comment: No, that's not. Subscriber is for the returned `Mono` from your `create()` method and is done somewhere in the HTTP request processor by the container.

Comment: the http request processor subscribes to the Mono produced from ok().body() which is Mono<ServerResponse> but the Mono<Domain> from reactive repository is resolved in call to fromObject??

Comment: That’s right, but subscription is done only once for the whole stream and the value is resolved on demand